# multiple pages of longtable on one landscape page

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable, longtable

I have a long two-column table. Is there any way to create something like this with r-markdown? (other than copy-pasting it out of the multipage output of longtable... )

Sorry if there is something obvious that I'm missing, but I really couldn't find a satisfying solution to this.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Could you post a link to input for such a table?  I forget all the details of longtable.  I'm guessing you could do this with the `multicol` LaTeX package; wrap the call to produce the table in `\begin{multicols}{4}` ... `\end{multicols}`, but I don't know how that interacts with `longtable`.

Comment: No, that doesn't work.  This link https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161455 gives some other ideas.

Comment: You can use the `DT` package that allows for Dynamic tables and appropriate pages, but you will have to edit the table to allow for the 3rd column, where you have it broken up by the **bolded** column names. but that would require an HTML output, and not a latex output